# grid.extra tableGrob Width specifiation

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, gridextra, r-grid

I am trying to specify the widths of columns in a table with 7 columns (header column + 6 data columns).

Previously, I was able to accomplish this by doing the following with a `gridExtra::tableGrob` object:

```
table$widths[c(1, 2, 3)] <- unit(c(0.17,.095, 0.175), "npc")
table$widths[c(4, 6)] <- table$widths[2]
table$widths[c(5, 7)] <- table$widths[3]
```

This worked fine previously, but for some reason, when I tried to rerun the same code now, I get the following error (when I don't specify the widths as given above, the table renders fine without any error):

```
grid.draw(p2_auc_table)
```

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
>     INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'

Does anyone have an suggestion as to what is wrong or of a better way of specifying widths?

Comment: Can you please provide input data that would help reproduce the error.  You can use `dput` to dump your data frame.